# Unable to get span tag using xpath

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

```
<div class="product_box">
    <div class="list_sale">
        <img src="link" class="listsale" alt="">
            <div class="product_box_title">
                <a href="link"><strong>title here</a></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="product_box_desc">
                some text here
                <strike>some text</strike> 
                <br />
                <span class="list_price">THIS IS THE NEEDED TEXT</span>
                <a href="link"><strong>some text</strong></a>
            </div>
            <div class="list_buynow">
            <form action="link" class="add_to_cart" method="post">
                <div class="add_cart">
                    <input type="image" src="link" value="add_to_cart" class="add_button">
                    <input id="fast_order_0_item_code" type="hidden" name="fast_order[0] [item_code]" value="value" class="item_code"/>
                    <input name="fast_order[0][add]" value="1" class="add_qty">
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="value">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
       <div class="product_box_img">
           <a href="link">
               <a href="link"><img src="http://stacktoheap.com/images/stackoverflow.png" alt=""></a>
           </a>  
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my html file and from this div I need to extract "THIS IS THE NEEDED TEXT". I Had been able to get the div with class "product_box_desc" and from that I am able to get the text under it "some text here". But I am unable to fetch the span which contains the text. Here is the XPATH query I am using, please suggest what has to be changed.

```
$dom_xpath->query("//div[@class='product_box']/div/div[@class='product_box_desc']/span[@class='list_price']")
```

Comment: Why you didn't use jQuery? Are you forced to use xml parser?

Comment: I have to parse through a complete site which contain similar html code block and fetch data from there to feed to csv file.

Answer (score 1):

This query works fine for me :

```
//div[@class="product_box"]/div[@class="list_sale"]/div[@class="product_box_desc"]/span[@class="list_price"]
```

But I change the html to this one :

```
<div class='product_box'>
    <div class='list_sale'>
        <img src='link' class='listsale' alt='' />
        <div class='product_box_title'>
            <a href='link'><strong>title here</strong></a>
        </div>
        <div class='product_box_desc'>
            some text here
            <strike>some text</strike> 
            <br />
            <span class='list_price'>THIS IS THE NEEDED TEXT</span>
            <a href='link'><strong>some text</strong></a>
        </div>
        <div class='list_buynow'>
        <form action='link' class='add_to_cart' method='post'>
            <div class='add_cart'>
                <input type='image' src='link' value='add_to_cart' class='add_button'>
                <input id='fast_order_0_item_code' type='hidden' name='fast_order[0] [item_code]' value='value' class='item_code'/>
                <input name='fast_order[0][add]' value='1' class='add_qty'>
                <input type='hidden' name='redirect_uri' value='value'>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
       <div class='product_box_img'>
           <a href='link'>
               <img src='http://stacktoheap.com/images/stackoverflow.png' alt=''>
           </a>  
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

One mistake was here :
`<a href='link'><strong>title here</strong></a>` instead of
`<a href='link'><strong>title here</a></strong>`

I do this :

```
$nodes = ($xPath->query('//div[@class="product_box"]/div[@class="list_sale"]/div[@class="product_box_desc"]/span[@class="list_price"]'));

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->textContent;
}
```

Comment: I have no control over the HTML, however that was a typo from my end, thanks for the change. But the result of the query is still: `DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )`

Comment: Is it **exactly** the same DOM tree? Down to the last comma?

Comment: The complete HTML file is very big and this just a portion of it, needless to say. I have removed extra spaces from the between the text. I don't think that should be a problem, however I can be wrong :)

Comment: Or you can make this query : `//*/*/span[@class="list_price"]` and then in the foreach, call `$DOMNode->getNodePath()` to see what's the path !

Comment: I am still getting `DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )`, there is no Node in the NodeList so no NodePath

Comment: Damn, It works for me... Maybe the trouble is somewhere else!

Comment: thats great, sure there is other part of the webpage causing issue. I think I have to check things all over again. thanks for help anyways.